# How to send **kwargs to a function with defined parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I'm looking for a way to **send **kwargs to a function with defined parameters**, without having to modify it.

**For example**, I want to pass the parameters as **kwargs when calling the following init method:

```
class ExampleClass(object):
def __init__(self, attr1=None, attr2=None, attr3=None):
    super(ExampleClass, self).__init__()
    self.attr1=attr1
    self.attr2=attr2
    self.attr3=attr3
```

Can anyone think of a way doing so?

Comment: You mean sending `attr1, attr2, attr3` to the super class constructor?

Comment: No. I have a class that gets parameters and creates an instance of another class. I don't want to pass them explicitly - I wish to pass them in a way that looks like this: ExampleClass(**kwargs).  Is it possible?

Comment: python 3 syntax would be different, you only need `super().init()`. please change accordingly

Comment: if you don't need to know the content, do you need to know the order of your args? it sounds like you can just use `*args` then

Comment: could you also give a brief example here for **"I have a class that gets parameters and creates an instance of another class"**, it'll be massively clearer for us to get right to the crux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExampleClass(**{"attr1":1, "attr2":2, "attr3":3})`

Comment: That's a nice idea that actually works, yet it's not what I'm looking for. Do you know of a way in which I won't have to know the attributes names? something that would look a bit like:

    ExampleClass(**kwargs)

where the **kwargs is something that I don't have to know it's content.

Comment: what's wrong with just using ExampleClass(**kwargs)

Comment: it's nothing wrong, it's just not what he wants. that simple.

Comment: Actually, minor modifications were enough to get me where I wanted. So.. It's what I needed. I just didn't know that :) thanks!

Comment: then could you post your modified version as an answer, for other people who stumble on the same problem, thanks!

Comment: you could use the `inspect` module to get the argument list for `__init__`: `inspect.getargspec(ExampleClass.__init__).args[1:]`